# dbus-send not working in shell script

Tags: linux, qt, shell, bluetooth, dbus

I want Bluetooth tethering between my laptop (Debian 8) and my smartphone (Android).

At the arch linux wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android_tethering#Tethering_via_Bluetooth) i found this command: `bus-send --system --type=method_call --dest='org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C0_EE_FB_20_D7_00' org.bluez.Network1.Connect string:'nap'`

When i execute it in the normal terminal everything works fine. For my purpose i need to call this command in a QT application. Because of this i created a shell script. But when executing the script nothing happens. Same result when calling the command inside a new shell (`sh`).

Does anybody have an idea how to get this working or another way? My normal terminal is the default Debian terminal, '`Root Terminal`'.

Thank you

Comment: I'd start with checking the environment the script is running in, e.g. does it have a session bus (which I assume you are using), etc. If the environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is not set you could use some other address to the dbus-send command or set the variable prior to the call. If you run it from a Qt app see how you can copy the current environment to the environment where the call will be made for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Other dbus-send commands worked find. I managed it now using QTs DBus classes and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the QDBus object. First i create the following two methods:

```
QString MainWindow::getDBusInterface(){
    QString interface = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev";
    QStringList macParts = ui->selectedMac->text().toUpper().split(":");
    for (int i = 0; i < macParts.length(); i++){
        interface.append("_").append(macParts[i]); //MAC address to connect to from GUI
    }
    return interface;
}
```

and

```
QDBusMessage MainWindow::sendDBus(QString destination, QString path, QString interface, QString method, QList<QVariant> arguments){
    QDBusMessage response;


    QDBusConnection system = QDBusConnection::systemBus();
    if (!system.isConnected())
    {
        qFatal("Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.");
        return response;
    }

    QDBusMessage message2 = QDBusMessage::createMethodCall(destination, path, interface, method);

    message2.setArguments(arguments);


    // synchronous call (not recommended, blocking)
    response = QDBusConnection::systemBus().call(message2);
    qDebug() << "response is: " << response;

    return response;
}
```

Finally i call:

```
QString interface = getDBusInterface();

QList<QVariant> arguments;
arguments.append("nap");
QDBusMessage response = sendDBus("org.bluez",
                                     interface,
                                     "org.bluez.Network1",
                                     "Connect",
                                     arguments);
```